# Deleting firefox profile folder from java

Tags: java

I am starting a firefox with a temporary firefox profile folder. When the user closes swing UI, I am destroying the process using java.lang.Process#destroy. And when I immediately try to remove the folder, it throws exception since the firefox process has not terminated yet.

Is there a way to remove the directory when the process has terminated completely without adding a delay(Thread.sleep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're starting Firefox from Java  as Proces, you may use [Process.waitFor()](http://tinyurl.com/bebusn2) in order to wait for Firefox to terminate. And then remove temporary folder.

Comment: `Process#waitFor()` waits for the process to terminate on its own.  Firefox doesn't terminate on its own unless it crashed.  Unless `waitFor()` works after calling `destroy()`, this approach won't work.

Comment: I invoke waitFor after invoking destroy.